# Is it permissable to drink water if you woken at the call of fajr prayer during Ramadan

Tags: quran, hadith

Is it permissable to drink water when you have woken at the call of fajr prayer during Ramadan.

Comment: When was the call of fajr? On time or later?

Answer (score 1):

The call for **Fajr Prayer** begins when the **Sehri** time gets over so you can't drink water once the **Sehri** time is over and remember that the **Adhaan/Azan** has no relation with **Sehri**. It's just a reminder for the Prayer.
A better practice is to observe the time chart as it contains the start and finish time for each **Prayer**, **Sehri** and **Iftari** etc.

Answer (score 0):

Please keep in mind that end of sehri time has no relation with azaan.  If time of sehri is ended in your region then you are not allowed to eat or drink...
Jzk

Comment: There's no time of sohoor in Islam any meal before fajr adhan (on time as it should be) is sohoor when one intends to fast. So it certainly is related to adhan.